# Randomize a winner pair from the subscriptions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a project, where customer needs a winnner pair for events. The users of this site can "like" other user's (just like on FB), they subscribe to a particular post, and the script will generate a winner pair from the subscribers.

So I need a SQL query to randomize a winner pair from the list of pairs, where the users liked each other, and subscribed to a particular post.

How do i do that ?
I cant write a query that, because i got unexpected results.

I have 3 tables : events, likes, subs (and users ofc)

```
events table : event_id, event_name
subs table: sub_id, event_id, uid
likes table: liker, liked (the two uid from the users table)
```

Now I can make pairs from the likes table (i self-joined the table `where liker = liked AND liked = liker`) and randomized, but how can I join the subs and the events tables to the likes table to achieve that a randomized pair will be a subscribed users for a particular event too ?

My current query looks like this :

```
SELECT L.liked AS T1, L.liker AS T2
        FROM likes AS L, likes AS K
        WHERE L.liked = K.liker
        AND L.liker = K.liked
        ORDER BY rand( )
        LIMIT 0 , 1
```

I googled everything about joins for one week, but i cant achieve that.

Comment: a) you should always use explicit joins, not the comma-version. E.g. `FROM likes AS L join likes AS K
on L.liked = K.liker and L.liker = K.liked`. Both work the same way, but it is clearer what you are doing, especially if you add more `join`. b) to `join` more table with more conditions, you can just add another `join...on`, and another, and another, e.g. `... join subs s1 on s1.uid = l.liker join events e on e.event_id = s1.event_id join subs s2 on s2.uid = l.liked and s2.event_id = e.event_id`. (There are of course a lot of other ways to write that.)

Comment: Looks like it worked, thank you !